# How to add UIVisualEffectView to UINavigationBar in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use UIVIsualEffectView to add blurry effect to Navigation Bar. I have custom navigation bar class as following.
Header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GSNavigationBar : UINavigationBar
@end
```

And immplementation file looks like following

```
#import "GSNavigationBar.h"

@implementation GSNavigationBar

- (void) awakeFromNib {

     UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight]];
     visualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -21, self.frame.size.width , self.frame.size.height + 21);
     [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
     [self insertSubview:visualEffectView atIndex:1000];
}
@end
```

With the code above I am able to implement blurry effect to Navigation Bar. Upon pushing a view controller (by using 'Push' segue), left bar button items and right bar items in the navigation bar become inactive. For more clarity I have attached screenshots of the view controllers.

[This is view controller #1. All navigation item buttons are clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2mMr.png)

[This is view controller #2. We land up here due to push segue from view controller #1. Navigation item buttons are NOT clickable. Also the title goes missing. I had set the title using self.title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK1NO.png)

Comment: Why are you adding an empty image to the navigation bar? Navigation bar already has a blur effect, you should use that.

Answer (score 1):

NavigationBar with `translucent = YES` already has a blur effect.

So just use it.

Comment: I modified the code add currently my code looks like

    - (void) awakeFromNib {
        self.translucent = YES;
    }

Does NOT produce desired effect. Am I missing something here?

Comment: it should work with simple - (void)awakeFromNib {self.translucent = YES};

Comment: Sorry  self.translucent = YES; doesn't produce desired effect.

Comment: you can control the color of navigationBar by setting, self.tintColor = [UIColor someColor];  maybe this will help you

Comment: Nope. tintColor changes the color of UIBarButtons. I have tried all- barTint, tintColor, backgroundColor along with different alphas of the color. Adding UIVisualEffectView gives the perfect effect I am looking for.

Comment: checkout answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308842/real-time-blur-effect-for-navigation-bar

Answer (score 1):

This is to make navigation bar fully transparent, if you have blurred background I believe it will be effect that you needed.

Swift:

```
func setupNavigationBar() {
    navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true
}
```

Objective C:

```
- (void) setupNavigationBar{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self sendSubviewToBack:visualEffectView];
```

Answer (score 0):

set the property UserInteractionEnabled to NO (false in swift) on the UIVisualEffect.

so on your code you should add:

```
visualEffectView.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

this should make your navigationItems left and right usable