# Real time blur effect for Navigation Bar - Status bar not getting in

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308842/real-time-blur-effect-for-navigation-bar) to get real time blur effect in Navigation Bar:

```
func addBlurEffect() {
var bounds = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds as CGRect!
var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
visualEffectView.frame = bounds
visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleWidth
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)
}
```

But the status bar remains translucent:

[image]

How to fix it?

---

Debugging:

```
    print(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds)
    // Returns (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)

    print(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame)
    // Returns (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 20.0)
```

Comment: Have a look on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308842/real-time-blur-effect-for-navigation-bar/27316465#27316465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's partly because you set the visual effect view's frame to the navigation bar's bounds. What you see in the screen shot *are* the navigation bar's bounds. So, you might be able to compensate by giving your visual effect view a different frame, i.e. move its origin up 20 points and increase its height.

It's a little unclear to me, though, why you don't just make the navigation bar translucent. Navigation bar translucency *is* the blur effect, and it is supported. What you're doing — adding a subview to the navigation bar — is not.

Comment: Hey @matt, I'm using [LTNavigationBar](https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationBar) library. I could not make it work with the straightforward ".translucent" way. I managed to adjust the bounds from your answer, thanks. I will add it if someone else need it.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it. Next time, please give relevant information (like, you're using some third-party library) _when you ask your question_. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working adding this:

```
bounds.offsetInPlace(dx: 0.0, dy: -20.0)
bounds.size.height = bounds.height + 20.0
```

Comment: This merely does what I said to do; it adds nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As for this problem, I have modified Kampai's earlier answer, which the original was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27316465/6467953).

The code below would blur the status bar as well as navigation bar.

Swift 4:

```
func navigationBarBlur() {
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: -20.0, width: UserDefaults.screenWidth, height: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.size.height)! + 20.0)
    let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
    self.visualEffectView = visualEffectView
    visualEffectView.frame = bounds
    visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)
}
```