# how to get a blurred effect behind my UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

I have been trying to get an effect of having my scrollView appear under the navigationBar slightly blurred as is the case in the apple messages app.  I have tried the following methods and none of them has worked:

1:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

2:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.blackTranslucent
```

3:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

4:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear()
```

I have read many posts with variations of the above methods and have tried most of them but to no avail.  I thought the point of setting isTranslucent = true was to get exactly that effect.  Is there something else I should be trying?  Basically I just want my navigationBar to be slightly see-through.

Answer (score 4):

`UIVisualEffectView` is what you are looking for, and well demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308842/real-time-blur-effect-for-navigation-bar):

```
let bounds = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds as CGRect!
let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))
visualEffectView.frame = bounds
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```

That said, use your method 1 and 2 together should also work:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Contacts";
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds)!
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can add this code for your navigation bar blur effect this function is perfect for you

```
func navigationBlurEffect() {
    // Add blur view
    let bounds = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds as CGRect!
    let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))
    visualEffectView.frame = bounds
    visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

    //here you can choose one 
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)
    // Or
    /*
 If you find that after adding blur effect on navigationBar, navigation buttons are not visible then add below line after adding blurView code.
    */ 
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.sendSubviewToBack(visualEffectView)

    // Here you can add visual effects to any UIView control.
    // Replace custom view with navigation bar in above code to add effects to custom view.
}
```

[image]

//**This is only for Image Blur code 
And this code you can use for Image Blur effect

```
  func getImageBlur(image:UIImageView){
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = (image.bounds)
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        image.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
```