# Blur effect on navigation bar while using a tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

[Real time blur effect for Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308842/real-time-blur-effect-for-navigation-bar)

Tried the solution mentioned in the above post,

AppDelegate.swift

```
// Sets background to a blank/empty image
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        // Sets shadow (line below the bar) to a blank image
        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        // Sets the translucent background color
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
        // Set translucent. (Default value is already true, so this can be removed if desired.)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = true
```

RootVC.swift

```
func addBlurEffect() {
        // Add blur view
        let bounds = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds as CGRect!
        let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))
        visualEffectView.frame = bounds
        visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.sendSubviewToBack(visualEffectView)

        // Here you can add visual effects to any UIView control.
        // Replace custom view with navigation bar in above code to add effects to custom view.
    }
```

In `viewDidLoad` used `self.addBlurEffect`.

Problem, is status bar is still not blurred, and the blur effect is restricted only to RootVC.swift.

How can I extend it to all sub VCs?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
bounds.offsetInPlace(dx: 0.0, dy: -20.0)
bounds.size.height = bounds.height + 20.0
```

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33071458/4283188)