# UIBlurEffect on StatusBar only (not on UINavigationBar)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

Similar to this:
[How to make a Navigation Bar and Status Bar blurred (UIBlurEffect)? iOS, Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781078/how-to-make-a-navigation-bar-and-status-bar-blurred-uiblureffect-ios-swift-3)

but we'd like to apply the UIBlurEffect on the StatusBar only, not the navigationbar. Is this possible?

Comment: Refer link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308842/real-time-blur-effect-for-navigation-bar/27316465

Comment: http://probably.ninja/implementing-a-super-simple-blurred-status-bar-on-ios-8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your statusBar view by following code, then try add to visual effect like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308842/real-time-blur-effect-for-navigation-bar/27316465)

```
     let statWindow = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey:"statusBarWindow") as! UIView
        let statusBar = statWindow.subviews[0] as UIView
//        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 23 / 255.0, green: 0 / 255.0, blue: 154 / 255.0, alpha: 0.7)
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 213 / 255.0, green: 0 / 255.0, blue: 0 / 255.0, alpha: 0.7)
```

Comment: It was easy to add the UIBlurEffect to this, thank you.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'App called -statusBar or -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead.

Comment: @Sentry.co pls check for updated code

Answer (score 1):

```
let statWindow = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey:"statusBarWindow") as! UIView
    let statusBar = statWindow.subviews[0] as UIView
    statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let blur = UIBlurEffect(style:.dark)
    let visualeffect = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
    visualeffect.frame = statusBar.frame
    //statusBar.addSubview(visualeffect)
    visualeffect.alpha = 0.5
    self.view.addSubview(visualeffect)
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 14/iOS 13 solution**: You can get your statusBar blur effect, by following code in your **viewDidLoad**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let blurryEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
    let blurredStatusBar = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurryEffect)
    blurredStatusBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(blurredStatusBar)
    blurredStatusBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    blurredStatusBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    blurredStatusBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    blurredStatusBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true }
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzCQG.png)