# My two attempts at getting a blurred background for a navigation title in SwiftUI are not working

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uinavigationbar, swiftui-navigationview

Beginner here making a simple todo list, but trying to get a blurred background only for the navigation title. I'm trying to do this with and without a UIViewRepresentable struct. Here is my method without the UIViewRepresentable struct.

"""

struct ContentView: View {

```
init() {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

    appearance.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)

    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance        
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}

var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                List {
                    ListEntry()
                }
                .opacity(0.8)
                .frame(height: geometry.size.height*(4/5))
            }
            VStack {
                // empty for now
            }
            }
        }
        .background(LeavesBackgroundView())
        .navigationTitle(Text("Monday, Apr 26"))
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Image(systemName: "gear"))
}
```

}

"""

..now with the UIViewRepresentable struct:

"""

struct  theBlurView: UIViewRepresentable {

```
@State var style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .systemMaterial

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
    let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
    uiView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
}
```

}

struct ContentView: View {

```
init() {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

    appearance.backgroundEffect = theBlurView(style: .regular) // error right here

    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance       
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}

var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                List {
                    ListEntry()
                }
                .opacity(0.8)
                .frame(height: geometry.size.height*(4/5))
            }
            VStack {
                // empty for now
            }
            }
        }
        .background(LeavesBackgroundView())
        .navigationTitle(Text("Monday, Apr 26"))
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Image(systemName: "gear"))
}
```

}

"""

In the second case, I get the error "Cannot assign value of type 'theBlurView' to type 'UIBlurEffect?'", but I cannot figure out a way to get them to be the same type.
In the first case, I get no error, but I get a white opaque navigation title background.

In both cases, I get this
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f22w2.jpg)

where the navigation title background is white. I've also tried different material styles (.dark, .light, .systemChromeMaterial, etc) and nothing makes it blurry.

[This is the kind of blur I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEJD2.png)

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Navigation Bar and Status Bar blurred (UIBlurEffect)? iOS, Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781078/how-to-make-a-navigation-bar-and-status-bar-blurred-uiblureffect-ios-swift-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you accept a third party library:

1. Install [SwiftUIX](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX)
2. Make blur with few lines of code by modify your NavBar `.background(VisualEffectBlurView(blurStyle: .systemThinMaterial))` and dont forget import SwiftUIX befor using.

Comment: @ShannonSlater if my answer helped you mark it accepted, thanks

Comment: ahh I see. I'm still new to stack overflow. Didn't know I could do that without at least 15 reputation