# Status bar Blur view (Translucent ) in swift 4.2 ios 12

Tags: ios, swift, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I am trying to blur the status bar depending on the background like it works when we pull down the status bar. like it is see through

```
        let statusBarFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
        let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        visualEffectView.frame = statusBarFrame
        view.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```

I have tried all styles but it does change to translucent
even I tried from storyboard effect shows in the storyboard but not in simulator even my **Reduce Transparency** is also turned on

[image]

I want to achive this in the stausbar

[image]

but it only gives a white bar

Answer (score 0):

You can get your statusBar view by following code, then try add to visual effect like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308842/real-time-blur-effect-for-navigation-bar/27316465)

```
     let statWindow = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey:"statusBarWindow") as! UIView
        let statusBar = statWindow.subviews[0] as UIView
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 213 / 255.0, green: 0 / 255.0, blue: 0 / 255.0, alpha: 0.7)
```

OR

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    func installBlurEffect() {
        isTranslucent = true
        setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        var blurFrame = bounds
        blurFrame.size.height += statusBarHeight
        blurFrame.origin.y -= statusBarHeight
        let blurView  = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        blurView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        blurView.frame = blurFrame
        blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(blurView)
        blurView.layer.zPosition = -1
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.installBlurEffect()
```

Comment: bro, I am not trying  to change the text color of the status bar I am trying to change the background to blur view as we see in a pull-up and down bar view in iPhone
I am not using the navigation bar I don't  know how to attach an image so I can show

Comment: Edited my answer, please check

Comment: no, it does not work the link you shared I wan that exact thing only in the status bar only I am not using  nav bar